# ASP.NET MVC 5 vs ASP.NET WebAPI for iOS Apps, Andoir Apps and WebApps

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I need to design a customers server architecture using the .NET framework. In the future the customer will implement several clients like native Android or iOS Apps or normal Web Apps written in HTML, CSS and JavaScript (AngularJS).

With which of the following approaches can I implement a more flexible and independent interface to clients built on different technologies like I mentioned above? Would be **ASP.NET MVC 5** or **ASP.NET WebAPI** the better choice?

Can I use both of them or is a solution with one of them even not possible?

Comment: Webapi should be good to go

Comment: you should go for ASP.NET Web API

Comment: As per my view, you should follow 
1. Asp.net MVC 5 or other web platform for website/webapp.
2. Android / ios client,  And then
but you should develop and host ASP.NET Web API as different project that can server all of your clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should go for ASP.Net WebAPI, Enlisting few reasons why :

1. **Web API** helps to build `REST-ful` services over the **.NET Framework** and it also support *content-negotiation(it's about deciding the best response format data that could be acceptable by the client. it could be JSON,XML,ATOM or other formatted data)*, self **hosting which are not in MVC.**
2. Web API also ***takes care of returning data in particular format like JSON,XML or any other based upon the Accept header in the request and you don't worry about that***. MVC only return data in JSON format using **JsonResult**.
3. Asp.Net Web API is new framework and part of the core ASP.NET framework. The model binding, filters, routing and others MVC features exist in Web API are different from MVC and exists in the new System.Web.Http assembly. In MVC, these featues exist with in System.Web.Mvc. Hence Web API can also be used with Asp.Net and as a stand alone service layer.

Comment: Thank you that sounds plausible! REST with JSON would be easy to use in mobile or web clients.

Comment: Correct, In fact scalability is much more simplified