# MVC .NET or WEB API

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

We want to write a new web site for customer using SQL DB
and implement only one specific client.

what the recommended technology to be used:

- Peure MVC.net
- Web API and client side using AJAX

I will be glad to hear the causes, the consideration and the cost.

Thanks!

Comment: Just gave this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762633/asp-net-mvc-5-vs-asp-net-webapi-for-ios-apps-andoir-apps-and-webapps/34762728#34762728

Comment: if you just want an web application(for desktop only) then go for MVC, if you want more devices like phone and tablet then go for Web API

Answer (score 1):

I tend to favour a web api to handle all of the database work (via entity framework), but use MVC for my front end application.

This way you have all the flexibility of an API should you want to use different frameworks in the future (Angular, ASP.net 5 etc), but you can still have the pleasure of working MVC in your front end site.